# Testing in Play Framework 2.2 with Java + JPA: How to make transactions last?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I try to test actions of my Play app, but I can't get my changes do the database to be persistent. Every change to the database I do within a callAction() seems to be rolled back in the end. In development/production mode the action works fine, changes to the DB are persistent.

This is my test class:

```
public class StackOverflowControllerTest {

    protected static FakeApplication application;
    protected static EntityManager entityManager;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void startApp() throws Exception {
        application = Helpers.fakeApplication();
        Helpers.start(application);

        Option<JPAPlugin> jpaPlugin = application.getWrappedApplication()
                .plugin(JPAPlugin.class);
        entityManager = jpaPlugin.get().em("default");
        JPA.bindForCurrentThread(entityManager);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void stopApp() throws IOException {
        entityManager.close();
        JPA.bindForCurrentThread(null);
        Helpers.stop(application);
    }

    @Test
    public void callSubmit() throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> form = new HashMap<String, String>();
        form.put(ComponentModel.TITLE, "Title Test");

        EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        // This call should create an entity in the DB, but doesn't.
        // The surrounding transaction shouldn't be necessary. I do
        // it just in case. It doesn't change with or without.
        FakeRequest request = fakeRequest().withFormUrlEncodedBody(form);
        Result result = callAction(controllers.routes.ref.Components.create()), request);
        transaction.commit();

        assertEquals(SEE_OTHER, status(result));

        ComponentModel component = JPA.em().find(ComponentModel.class, 1);
        // The component doesn't exist in the DB any more, although it was created in the callAction().
        assertNotNull(component);
    }
}
```

The actual controller method does the standard. It uses JPA.em().persist() to persist the model.

```
@Transactional
public static Result create() {
    Form<ComponentModel> form = Form.form(ComponentModel.class)
            .bindFromRequest();
    ComponentModel component = form.get();
    JPA.em().persist(component);
    return ok();
}
```

I have a configuration file for testing that is used instead of application.conf. Here I use an in-memory DB, while in development/production it's MySQL.

```
# Database configuration - H2 database
# ~~~~~
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:test/jatos;MODE=MYSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"
```

My persistance.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="h2PersistenceUnit"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
            <!-- Maintain the schema to follow any changes of the models -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="mysqlPersistenceUnit"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <!-- Maintain the schema to follow any changes of the models -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

I'm using Play 2.2.3. Any clue why the changes within a callAction() aren't persistent?

Comment: Provide the contents of Components.create.

Comment: @Salem: added controller method Components.create().

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not related to transactions (so remove them from your test code), but due the fact you are not providing any form data (so probably `form.get()` returns nothing).

Supposing you are using a form to post the data, you can provide the form data using something like this:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("component_id", "1");
map.put("component_name", "Some component");
// (...)
Result result = callAction(
    controllers.routes.ref.Components.create(),
    fakeRequest().withFormUrlEncodedBody(map)
)
```

Comment: Thank you Salem for your reply, but that's not the problem. I shortened my code to make it more obvious what I want to say. In the original I use .withFormUrlEncodedBody(map) on the fakeRequest. Sorry for the confusion. I updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the inMemoryDatabase() ?? Thats what you need to use to test the DB. In this example i persist a computer before, but you can use evolutions in order to have default values.

```
@Test
public void findById() {
    running(fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase("test")), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

        JPA.withTransaction(new play.libs.F.Callback0() {
            @Override
            public void invoke() throws Throwable {
                JPA.em().persist(new Computer(21l, "Macintosh"));
            }
        }); 
            Computer macintosh = Computer.findById(21l);
            assertEquals("Macintosh", macintosh.name);
        }
    });
}
```

Here you have more information
[PlayFramework Doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaFunctionalTest)

Comment: Yes, I'm using the H2 in-memory DB. It's loaded in `@BeforeClass` method `startApp()`: `entityManager = jpaPlugin.get().em("default");`

Comment: Whether I use `JPA.withTransaction` or `JPA.em().getTransaction().begin();` together with `JPA.em().getTransaction().commit();` has no influence. In both ways the changes done within the callAction() aren't persisted. This only happens within a callAction() - if I change the DB directly - like `JPA.em().persist(new Computer(21l, "Macintosh"));` - it works nicely.